# Contact form working but sends blank fields sometimes

Tags: php, contact-form

I have a contact form that works fine but I receive emails with blank fields sometimes. They can come 6 in 5 minutes.There doesn't seem to be a pattern. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Here is the html

```
<form id="form-contact" method="post" action="contact.php">
  <div class="span6 center white"><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" /></div>
  <div class="span6 center white"><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" /></div>
  <div class="span6 center"><textarea cols="6" rows="4" placeholder="Message" name="contact_message" id="contact_message"></textarea></div>
  <div class="span12 center"><a href="" id="contact_send" class="btn btn-large btn-icon white"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>Send</a></div>
</form>
```

Here is the contact.php

```
$to = 'email@email.com'; 

ini_set('SMTP', 'email@email.com');

ini_set('smtp_port', '26');
if($to) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $html = "";
    $html .= "Name: " . htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . "\n";
    $html .= "Email: " . htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . "\n";
    $html .= "Message: " . htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . "\n";


    $headers .= "From: " . $name . "<". $email .">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";

    $html = utf8_decode($html);

    mail($to, $subject, $html, $headers);

    if ($html)
        echo 'ok';
    else
        echo 'error';

} else {
    echo "error";   
}

?>
```

Comment: You're getting blank fields because you do not have any conditional statements. I.e.: `if(empty($_POST['contact_name'])){ die("Fill in your name."); }`

Comment: Do you validate the form? If no then are you sure that your `$_POST` value actually have any data? I think it should be `$_POST['contact_name']` unless and until you change it in the js.

Comment: Same thing goes for `name="contact_email"` with `$email = $_POST['email'];` and the others --- it's back to the 'ol drawing board ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes. true. just gave an example of one field.. :)

Comment: This one (question) falls into what I call, the `C.O.W.` code category. @Grish

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know too much about PHP. I paid someone to do this and it works, but I get random emails as if I hit the send button and didn't fill out the form. When I try to just hit the send button without filling in the form I get an error message and I don't get a blank email.